# How to Convert Single quoted elements of Array into just comma separated string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string

I have a array like

let array = ["MR','JR','IR','MY"]

I want to convert it into a comma separated String like

string = MR,JR,IR,MY

Any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Comment: Yes tried this but not got the result what I expected @MarkBaijens

Comment: If you define your array correctly (same quotes everywhere) then it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/dvcgjs2w/

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the join method with comma as a separator

```
let string = array.join(',')
```

**EDIT**:
Actually your array have only one position, so you are not joining anything. You only need to replace the character `'` and you are done.

```
let string = array[0].replace(new RegExp("'", "g"),"")
```

Comment: Already tried this but results look like this 
string = MR','JR','IR','MY

only the two outermost quotes were removed not each quotes were

Comment: If that's the actual result then you called `.join()` with `"','"`. Just use `.join()` without any argument, which is the same as `.join(",")`

Comment: I did that only i have not used any other code just used .join() only

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it